Undefined variable $form on remote server
I created simple app and after deploying app on remote server i have issue with code.
But.. on my local machine this code works fine, i even pulled code again from git and installed again on my local machine and it's working without any issues.
Error that i have after visiting app.com:

Undefined variable $form

web.php:
Route::view('/', 'home')
    ->middleware(['auth']);

View home.blade.php
...
    <div>
        <livewire:ListQrcode />
    </div>

Livewire component: ListQrcode.php
class ListQrCode extends Component
{
    public $qrCodes;
    public QrCode $selectedQrCode;
    public string $selectedTitle = '';
    public string $selectedDescription = '';
    public string $selectedCode = '';
    public bool $createQrcode = false;
    public bool $showDrawer2 = false;
    public CreateQrcode $form;

    public function render()
    {
        $this->qrCodes = QrCode::with('tags')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        return view('livewire.ListQrcode',
            ['qrCodes' => $this->qrCodes]
        );
    }
}

Livewire Form:
class CreateQrcode extends Form
{
    #[Validate('required', 'string', 'min:3')]
    public $code = '';

    #[Validate('required', 'string', 'max:255')]
    public $title = '';

... 
}


View that code throw error,
                <div class="flex justify-center min-h-[296px] p-8">
                    @if($form->code)
                        <div class="p-4 dark:bg-gray-600 rounded-lg">
                            {!! QrCode::size(200)->generate($form->code) !!}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>

From some reason, PHP don't see $form variable on remote machine, when i comment problematic variable in template, then i have issue with another variable that is undefined.
What i should check to resolve that problem? It's seems that PHP have issues with visibility of variables somehow.
Local machine:

Windows 11
NGINX
PHP 8.3

Remote machine:

Ubuntu 23
NGINX
PHP 8.3


So, I finally resolved issue.
On one discord server (LaravelDaily), one user pointed to file name collisions as the cause. Windows ignores such problems, on the other hand, for Linux it is a problem.
The problem was in the naming of two files:

app/Livewire/ListQrCode.php (correct name)
resources/views/livewire/ListQrCode.blade.php ( should be list-qr-code.blade.php)

And in the home.blade.php file
<livewire:ListQrcode />
should be
<livewire:list-qr-code />
The whole problem could have been avoided if I had followed the correct naming convention :)

Run php artisan config:clear and php artisan view:clear on your remote server. Sometimes, cached views or configurations can cause issues.

I done that already, i tried:

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan views:clear
composer dump-autoload
Checked permissions to /storage and /bootstrap/cache

When i launch app on Windows, everything works fine (checked on 2 PC), when I launch on Linux (2 different machines) i have this error.
From what i see, Laravel not loading Livewire class but only livewire view. Even when i remove PHP file and leave only blade.php i have same error :|

You should pass the $form variable to the view from the render() method in your ListQrCode component.
public function render()
{
    $this->qrCodes = QrCode::with('tags')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    return view('livewire.ListQrcode', [
        'qrCodes' => $this->qrCodes,
        'form' => $this->form
    ]);
}


$form variable is passed by Livewire, no need to pass this to view :)
